# AttributeError: 'Categorical' object has no attribute 'cat'

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

In python dataframe while getting category codes after assigning a column to variable(`y=df.column`) is giving attribute error.

[image].

While same is working fine if we directoly pass `df.column` to `Categorical` function.

[image]

Comment: Please don't add your code as pictures. See [creating good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and create a [mcve]

Comment: Rolling back your edit because it completely muddles up your post. Please copy paste the exact code in your images into your question, or not at all.

Comment: pd.Categorical(df.c1) gives `arrays.categorical.Categorical` object while `series.Series` object

Answer (score 4):

The `.cat` attribute is a **categorical accessor** associated with `categorical` dtype Series:

```
s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'a']).astype('category') 
s                                                                                            
0    a
1    b
2    a
dtype: category
Categories (2, object): [a, b]

s.cat.codes                                                                                                                               
0    0
1    1
2    0
dtype: int8
```

OTOH, `pd.Category` returns a `pandas.core.arrays.categorical.Categorical` object, which has these attributes **defined on the object directly**:

```
pd.Categorical(['a', 'b', 'c'])                                                                                                           
# [a, b, c]

pd.Categorical(['a', 'b', 'c'])  .codes                                                                                                                                   
# array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int8)
```

Comment: while printing 'y' and 'df.c1' both seems to be as categorical type

Comment: @VikashYadav Please carefully look at your code and images, they do not corroborate. Anyway, the whole point of my answer, is that `df['c1']` is a Series, while `pd.Categorical(...)` (and anything you assign it to) is a Categorical object.